# How do you assign new variable names when its already assigned to something? Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

The title really really doesn't explain things. My situation is that I would like to read a file and put the contents into a hash. Now, I want to make it clever, I want to create a loop that opens every file in a directory and put it into a hash. Problem is I don't know how to assign a name relative to the file name. eg:

```
hash={}  
Dir.glob(path + "*") do |datafile|
  file = File.open(datafile)
  file.each do |line|
    key, value = line.chomp("\t")
    # Problem here is that I wish to have a different
    # hash name for every file I loop through
    hash[key]=value
  end
  file.close
end
```

Is this possible?

Comment: How about a hash of hashes with the first hash having keys being the filenames? Would that work?

Comment: Ah, I see some people beat me to it below! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to dynamically create variables with the names of the files you process?

try this:

```
Dir.glob(path + "*") do |fileName|
  File.open(fileName) {

    # the variable `hash` and a variable named fileName will be
    # pointing to the same object... 
    hash = eval("#{fileName} = Hash.new")

    file.each do |line|
      key, value = line.chomp("\t")
      hash[key]=value
    end
  }
end
```

Of course you would have to make sure you rubify the filename first. A variable named "bla.txt" wouldn't be valid in ruby, neither would "path/to/bla.csv"

Comment: Note though that you won't be able to access the newly created variables without eval. Also filenames containing spaces or quotes (among other things) would break this approach.

Comment: I'm not sure "solving the file the requested way" is necessarily a virtue. If the questioner knew enough to be certain what the best way was, he probably wouldn't be here.

Comment: @Chuck how else would you do it? Please Educate me! Thanks

Comment: I'm not chuck, but I would do it the way jug proposed, because a) it works with all filenames and b) you don't need eval to access the hashes afterwards.

Comment: Yep, I like jug's solution better. I'm not voting this down or anything — I just think this may not be the best of all possible solutions.

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you use a hash whose keys are the file names (in your case "datafile") and whose value are hashes in which you insert your data?

```
hash = Hash.new { |h, key| h[key] = Hash.new }  
Dir.glob(path + '*') do |datafile|
  next unless File.stat(datafile).file?
  File.open(datafile) do |file|
    file.each do |line|
      key, value = line.split("\t")
      puts key, value
      # Different hash name for every file is now hash[datafile]
      hash[datafile][key]=value
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You can replace `File.open` and `file.each` with `File.foreach(datafile) do |line|`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a dynamic variable, you can also use #instance_variable_set (assuming that instance variables are also OK.

```
Dir.glob(path + "*") do |datafile|               
  file = File.open(datafile)                     
  hash = {}                                      
  file.each do |line|                            
    key, value = line.chomp("\t")                
    hash[key] = value                            
  end                                            
  instance_variable_set("@file_#{File.basename(datafile)}", hash)    
end
```

This only works when the filename is a valid Ruby variable name. Otherwise you would need some transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do the following?

```
filehash = {} # after the File.open line

...
# instead of hash[key] = value, next two lines
hash[datafile] = filehash
filehash[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use something like this:

```
hash[file] = {}
hash[file][key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Two hashes is enough now.
fileHash -> lineHash -> content.